# Is it ok to return a locally initialised array, if no how can I do it?

Tags: java, arrays

Take this example:

```
public class foo
{
    public int[] func()
    {
        int arr[] = new int[3];
        // here initialised the array

        return arr;
    }
}
```

I'm not experienced with Java, but I know a little of C/C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's completely OK, because garbage collection is done when there is no further reference to the object. You can also find the array size by using `length` inside (`arr.length`) or outside (e.g. `aFoo.func().length`) the method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should be OK. Because Java arrays are allocated on heap not on stack. They wound't be collected after the function call returns.

Comment: Note that as mentioned elsewhere, in C++ the caller would have to be aware to delete the `new`ed array, even though it is similarly allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in both Java and C++.

The catch is in C++, you will heave to delete[] it manually sometime later to avoid memory leaks; while in Java, the garbage collector will do its thing once there is no more references to the array, so you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to return the local array, but you must substantiate the returned data in the rest of your program so it continues serving a purpose.

Relate the data to something new.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly OK in C# world.

You also can do this: `return new int[] {1,2,3,4};`